# How to stretch or shrink subtable inside of resizebox accordingly?

Tags: tables

How to resize subtable inside of resizebox?
I want to have three-tables side-by-side. However, each table is too wide, so I am using \resizebox.
I realized that I need to set the width of subtable, where the effect of the \resizebox is not there. How can we set some sort of relative width?

```
\begin{table*}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
  \begin{subtable}[h]{XXX} % how to set XXX?
  \caption{$M=14$}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
       % stuff
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}

  \begin{subtable}[h]{XXX} % how to set XXX?
  \caption{$M=14$}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
       % stuff
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}


  \begin{subtable}[h]{XXX} % how to set XXX?
  \caption{$M=14$}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
       % stuff
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}

  }
\end{table*}
```

Comment: don't use \resizebox to fit a tabular, you will get uneven font sizes and it simply looks bad. Set the fontsize instead, e.g. with \footnotesize

Comment: Don't use `resizebox` to make sure a table fits into the available space as this will only lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout your document. There are better ways, some of which are listed here: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) If you provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including some representative example contents in the tables, we could make some alternative suggestions on how to make the tables fit.

Comment: Having had a closer look at your table code: Do you really expect three tables with 16 columns each to fit side by side into the textwidth? Even if the contents of each cell are exceptionally short I don*t think you can squeeze the tables into the textwidth while still keeping them at a readable font size.